# Bluetooth device disconnected right after pairing 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

Bluetooth works fine when I connected to my Bluetooth mouse. I paired a new device the same, but after Bluetooth pairing is done it disconnected. There's no way of switching it on to connect. I tried running this command `sudo pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-discover` This is what it gave me
`No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused`

Pls help